# Create a list of all values from one sheet that match a cell on another

Tags: excel, vba, list, arraylist

Ok I need to build a list automatically on Sheet2 (In Column A from Row 2 down).

If I enter the data "Team 1" into A1 on Sheet2, I need it to pull anyones names from Sheet1 Column B. (Column A has the Team # they are on).

I've tried the following and have had no luck.

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$4)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")

Wouldn't produce anything.

I've seen a VBA code in the past that worked similar but couldn't find it to try to manipulate it to work in this case.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wclmIcTsbtg) may be helpful. Just that you have to paste it vertical. Note that it is array formula .. Wouldn't produce anything? There is no reference to Sheet1 in the formula

Comment: I keep getting the #Name? response when I try it.                              
=INDEX('Sheet1'!A13:A500,SMALL(IF('Sheet1'!A13:A500=Sheet2!A1,ROW('Sheet1'!A13:A500)-1,Coulmns(Sheet2!A2:A2)),2))                                                                                       I need it to do it automaticly when I update the value in A1 on Sheet 2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use this in the code module for Sheet2 ...

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim vSourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim VRow As Range
    Dim VTargetCounter As Long

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        ' clear out the names in the target column
        Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Clear

        ' read through Sheet1 and populate names into Sheet2
        VTargetCounter = 2
        Set vSourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each VRow In vSourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & vSourceSheet.Range("A" & vSourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            If VRow.Cells(1, 1) = Target.Value2 Then
                Target.Cells(VTargetCounter, 1) = VRow.Cells(1, 2)
                VTargetCounter = VTargetCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting an error when I try it. "Compile error: Variable not defined". It highlights vROW in the 8th line

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so much

Comment: @JoshTodd if this answers your question please tick/ accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution using `Dictionary` object

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then Exit Sub

    Dim teamRng As Range
    With Sheet1
        Set teamRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    If teamRng.Find(what:=Target.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim names As Variant
    Dim cel As Range
    With CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        For Each cel In teamRng
            .Item(cel.Value) = .Item(cel.Value) & cel.Offset(, 1).Value & " "
        Next

        names = Split(Trim(.Item(Target.Value2)), " ")
        Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(names) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(names)
    End With


SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```